# typeid does not return derived class when called from DLL

Tags: c++, templates, dll, polymorphism, typeid

I'm using `typeid` to produce debug outputs for my application. I rely on the polymorphic behaviour of `typeid` on dereferenced pointers to base classes.

Now I came across a problem that either is a compiler bug or some weird type deduction rule not obvious at first sight.

I have a common base class taking a template parameter, which is defined in a  common header file:

```
class Type {};
template<typename T>  class Base { virtual void dummy() {} };
```

Then I have two DLLs:

- one which contains a derived class of `Base<Type>` and an instance thereof.

  ```
  #include "commonheader.h"

  class Derived : public Base<Type> { };
  Derived instance;
  main() { CallDLL(&instance); }
  ```
- and another one which has a function to work with a pointer to `Base<Type>`. This function is called with the address of the instance in the first DLL.

  ```
  #include "commonheader.h"

  void CallDLL(Base<Type>* b_ptr)
  {
      std::string typeName1 = typeid(*b_ptr).name();
      std::string typeName2 = typeid(*&*b_ptr).name();
  }
  ```

As far as I know `typeName1` should evaluate to `"class Derived"`, since `*b_ptr` it is a dereferenced pointer to a polymorphic base class. However, it doesn't. The result is `"class Base<class Type>"`.
Most surprisingly, when adding another layer of indirection, `typeName2` is indeed `"class Derived"`.

**So the main problem here is that `typeid(*b_ptr) != typeid(*&*b_ptr)`, which should never happen.**

As you can see, the second version solves my original problem of getting a debug output name for the most derived class pointed to by `b_ptr`. But I can't explain why and I wonder if this is the intended behaviour.

A few further remarks:

- I am using Visual Studio 2010. I haven't tested another compiler.
- It is not possible to simplify the problem any further:

  - putting the definition of `Derived` in the header produces the correct output.
  - putting everything together in one DLL (or EXE) produces the correct output.
  - removing the template parameter from `Base` produces the correct output.

Thanks for your help!